# get pandas dataframe group meeting condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe say with columns as course, section, student_id
Each course can have one or more sections, each section one or more students:
course .   section    student_id
maths .    sec1 .     stu1
maths .    sec1 .     stu2
maths .    sec2 .     stu3
physics .  sec1 .     stu4
...
...

How can I get the following:
1. which course has the max students enrolled ?
2. looking at the top two sections with most students, which course has the most students enrolled?
I am able to get the max value, but how can I get the group with the max

Apart from using groupby, is it possible to do this using the course as index?

Comment: Why don't you want to use groupby?

Comment: No problem in using groupby. Only curious if there is any other way to get the same results.

Comment: Another related problem: How to get the mean row within a group. In case none match the mean exactly - the two nearest ones.

Comment: I'd create another question for that. Just be sure to include a sample input and what your expected output is. Feel free to borrow my test `df` below or modify it to better suit the new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `DataFrame` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'course': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B', 'C'],
                   'section': [1,1,1,2,3,3,1,2, 1],
                   'student_id': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'fff', 'ggg']})
  course  section student_id
0      A        1        aaa
1      A        1        bbb
2      A        1        ccc
3      A        2        ddd
4      A        3        eee
5      A        3        aaa
6      B        1        aaa
7      B        2        fff
8      C        1        ggg
```

Then you can get the course with the maximum number of students as either:

```
df.groupby('course').size().idxmax()
#'A'
df.groupby('course').student_id.nunique().idxmax()
#'A'
```

In the first method, if a student is enrolled in multiple sections of the same course, they are double counted. In the second method they are not, so use which ever method is most appropriate

```
df.groupby('course').size()
#course
#A    6
#B    2
#C    1
#dtype: int64

df.groupby('course').student_id.nunique()
#course
#A    5
#B    2
#C    1
#Name: student_id, dtype: int64
```

For the possibility of ties don't use idxmax and instead see where the thing you calculate is equal to the max value:

```
class_size = df.groupby('course').size()
class_size[class_size==class_size.max()]
#course
#A    6
#dtype: int64
```

For the second part, you want to figure out which course has the maximum enrollment based on the top 2 most enrolled sections. You can accomplish this by calculating the section size and then adding together the two largest sections. (The drop duplicates ensures each section is only represented once)

```
df['sec_size'] = df.groupby(['course', 'section']).transform(np.size)

(df.drop_duplicates(['course', 'section'])
    .groupby('course').apply(lambda group: group.sec_size.nlargest(2).sum()))
#course
#A    5
#B    2
#C    1
#dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you very much. First one is exactly what I was looking for. Trying to understand the second solution.

Comment: Is there any simpler way for the second problem. May need more code, but that's okay.

Comment: The first line of the second part just calculates the size of each section within a course and brings that value back to EVERY ROW of the original dataframe for the proper section and course. Then you want the sum of the top two sections. Drop duplicates makes it so that each section is only represented once. (otherwise you would wind up adding the top section together twice). Then you group by the course and sum the value of section size for the 2 largest values.